# bash: aliasing for filtering lines with specified character count

Tags: bash, awk, alias

I want to filter lines on `bash` CLI that have a character count provided by the user.

While this can be done through `awk` (eg,`| awk -F+ 'NF==7'`), I want to alias this (say as `cfreq`) so that I can use it as follows:

```
$ cat foo | awk '$1 > 10' | cfreq 7 | wc
```

While the command can be generated by something simple such as printf (eg, `printf "awk -F+ NF==%s\n" 7`), I am unable to turn this into some alias that I can use across multiple systems though `.bashrc` file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: While the above requirement assumes the character `+` to be the reference character, if I can generalize that as well, it could be better. Eg:

```
$ cat foo | awk '$1 > 10' | cfreq + 7 | wc
```

I am not sure if this is too much to expect from aliasing, though I have been able to alias similar tasks in some cases.

Comment: Your command `printf "awk -F+ NF==%s\n" 7` prints literal awk command and `7`.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I cannot turn it into an alias.

Comment: I don't get it. Is `7` supposed to be an argument to awk?

Comment: No, the alias should create the equivalent of the above command, `awk -F+ 'NF==7'`.  The problem is the end of the escape quote.

Comment: a bit too confusing (for me) without some actual data to see what the final objective is; I'd suggest simplifying the examples ... eliminate the `cat/awk/wc` calls, show somse sample data to be processed by `cfreq`, and the actual code you want `cfreq` to implement (along with the expected output from the `cfreq` call); if the objective is to dynamically modify the `awk` code with the `cfreq` input parameter - `7` in this case - I'm thinking a function (instead of an alias) may be a better approach; and if `7` is a dynamic reference for `awk` ... `awk -F+ -v fldcnt=7 'NF==fldcnt'`

Comment: An alias is almost never the correct solution anyway. Create a function or a script.

Comment: The arguments of the alias will become arguments of the aliased command. While you can use `ARGV[1]` to get this value in `awk`, I'm not sure that you won't loose the capability of reading files from STDIN  and/or arguments. It'll be easier to define a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function instead of an alias:

```
cfreq() { local n="$1"; shift; awk -F'+' -v n="$n" 'NF==n' "${@:--}"; }
```

e.g.:

```
$ { printf '%s+' {1..8}; echo 9; } | cfreq 9
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9

$ { printf '%s+' {1..8}; echo 9; } | cfreq 7
$

$ { printf '%s+' {1..8}; echo 9; } > file
$ cfreq 9 file
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9
```

Comment: I would use `"${@--}"`, I may be wrong though

Comment: @Fravadona OK, here it is - `-` behaves differently when the variable/parameter it's being applied to is set but not populated, e.g. to try to output `5` if `x` is null we could do `x=''; echo "${x:-5}"` which does output `5` or we could try `x=''; echo "${x-5}"` but that outputs a blank line instead of `5`. So, is `"$@"` 1) unset or 2) set but not populated when no args are passed to a function? I don't know or care, I want the result to be `-` either way and so I use `"${@:--}"` for that and all other situations.

Comment: it seems that in the case of `"$@` those two expansions 100% are equivalent

Comment: I think you're probably right, I just prefer to always use `${whatever:-foo}` everywhere as that's always the behavior I want. If I ever did come across a situation when I need to do something different if `whatever` was unset vs set-but-not-populated then I'd consider using `${whatever-foo}`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not login after the question was initially locked. I made a small change to get it working for my requirement as given as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @EdMorton's answer, I am now able to get what I needed.

Added the `cfreq()` in `.bashrc`. Then it works beautifully!

```
$ cat test.txt
abc
abc + def
abc + def + ghi
abc + def + ghi
abc + ghi
$ cat test.txt | cfreq 2
abc + def
abc + ghi
$
```